# How to convert ionic app project from eclipse to android studio?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, ionic-framework

I am facing lot of problems due to the ionic plugins so I want to shift my project from eclipse to android studio. so please provide me steps regarding it.

Comment: Basically Ionic Android projects are naturally based on gradle, so it's not a big deal since Android Studio does a lot of indexing automatically anyways. Just head into Android Studio and open up the folder of the Android project inside of your Ionic project, wait until Android Studio has finished initial setup stuff and you should basically be good to go. If not it would be helpful if you could add the errors Android Studio shows to your question!